# non-conformable arguments with 3D matrix (tensor) multiplication in R

Tags: r, matrix, tensor

I have a 3D matrix, $X$, of dimension $T$ x $N$ x $k$ and I am trying to write an equation to solve for the coefficient vector.

```
X <-array(rnorm(T_*N*k),dim=c(T_,N,k)) # I used T_ to denote T
```

and I am trying to do

```
b <-solve((aperm(X,c(3,2,1))) %*% M %*% X)%*%(aperm(X,c(3,2,1))) %*% M %*% Y
```

where $b$ should be $k$ x $N$ since $Y$ is $T$ x $N$ and where $M$ is a $T$ x $T$ matrix. Yields the error

```
Error in (aperm(X, c(3, 2, 1))) %*% M : non-conformable arguments
```

Just an initial check of

```
dim(aperm(X,c(3,2,1)))
```

yields $k$ x $N$ x $T$ which is what I intended it to be. So I believe I can safely conclude `%*%` does not achieve what I thought it may.

I guess one solution is to transform $X$ to 2 dimensions with blocks, so that it will become $\tilde{X}$ with dimensions $NT$ x $k$ or maybe I need to loop over one of the dimensions in order to keep the structure the same? I am hoping to find a solution to solve it with the dimension structure as it is. Any thoughts/help is much appreciated...

Comment: There's a `tensor` package for R which contains a tensor product function.

Comment: Thank you very much, I feel silly for not having seen that prior to the post.